# Prove $T^{2}$ Hotelling central statistic

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I've been given the following definition of the **Hotelling distribution**:

Let $\underline{d}$~$N_{p}$($\underline{0},I_{p}$) *Multivariate normal distribution*

and $\textbf{W}$~(n,$I_{p}$) *Whishart distribution* independent between them,

then $T^2 \,= n \,\underline{d}^{t}\textbf{W}^{-1}\underline{d}$ ~ $T^2$  (Hotelling distribution)

-

I need to prove the Hotelling central statistic:

Lemma: Let $\underline{X}$~$N_{p}$($\underline{\mu},\sum$) and $\textbf{W}$~(n,$\sum$) independent then:

\begin{equation} T^2 = n(\underline{X}-\underline{\mu})^t\textbf{W}^{-1} (\underline{X}-\underline{\mu}) \sim T^2_{p,n}
\end{equation}

-

I've tried to standardize the Normal distribustion as it follows: 
$\sum^{-1}(\underline{X}-\underline{\mu})$ ~ $N_{p}(\underline{0},I_{p})$
and use the Wishart property that says that $CWC^{t} \sim W_{p}(n,CWC^{t})$ but I can't figure out the conclusion.

Thanks in advance to any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything settled, bad standardization.

$\sqrt{\sum}^{-1}(\underline{X}-\underline{\mu})$ ~ $N_{p}(\underline{0},I_{p})$

Now you can proceed without mistakes, just using the definition you will get to the conclusion.